# What does "newline" mean in the bash documentation?

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

The bash documentation says the following:

> A non-quoted backslash ‘\’ is the Bash escape character. It preserves
>   the literal value of the next character that follows, with the
>   exception of **newline**. If a \**newline** pair appears, and the backslash
>   itself is not quoted, the \**newline** is treated as a line continuation
>   (that is, it is removed from the input stream and effectively
>   ignored).

And the following:

> The backslash retains its special meaning only when followed by one of
>   the following characters: ‘$’, ‘`’, ‘"’, ‘\’, or **newline**. Within
>   double quotes, backslashes that are followed by one of these
>   characters are removed. Backslashes preceding characters without a
>   special meaning are left unmodified.

What is meant by "newline", is it the "n" character?

Comment: The same as in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Answer (score 3):

It refers to the literal newline character (LF, decimal no. 10 in ASCII), [the one at the end of each and every line](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_206). The backslash creates continuation lines, as in this script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo foo\
bar
```

The script contains `echo foo\↵bar`, which turns into `echo foobar` when the backslash-newline is removed. So it outputs `foobar`. (Try it.)

Comment: Not in all encoding is LF the last character of a line. It should be for UNIX of course.

Answer (score 1):

> What is meant by "newline", is it the "n" character?

No, it is not the n character. It is what `printf` prints in this command:

```
$ printf '\n'
```

It is as well the ASCII character number 10 (0a in hex) which is called "line feed (LF)" in [ASCII lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:USASCII_code_chart.png)

In fact, wikipedia has a [whole page about it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline).

If you want to see a numeric value (in hex) both this commands will show it:

```
$ printf '\n' | od -tx1
0000000 0a
0000001

$ printf '\n' | xxd -p
0a
```